# show/hide sharepoint field on custom edit form

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to find out how to control a sharepoint field on a custom edit form.  I need to either show/hide the field depending on what si inside of a column value in a related webpart on the same form.  I think jquery will solve it; the webpart was create dusing a joined subview.  Any ideas?

Comment: You should post code you have tried

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/ to do it :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="filelink/sharepointplus-3.0.4.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// do your test
if (/*your condition is */true) {
  $SP().formfields('Field to hide').row().hide()
}
</script>
```

If you don't want to use SharepointPlus, then it will depend:

1. test the "title" property of the field. For example if your column is called "First Name" and is a "input text" field, then you can do :

   ```
   jQuery("input[title='First Name']").closest('tr').hide()
   ```
2. if the "title" property doesn't work (all the Sharepoint fields don't use it), then you have to test all the "NOBR" tags in your page and look at the content to see if it's one of the field. For example if you want to hide the "username" column :

   ```
   jQuery('nobr').each(function() {
     var $this=$(this);
     if ($this.text() == "username") { $this.closest('tr').hide(); return false }
   })
   ```